# cannot import pandas_ta library in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandas-ta

I use jupyter notebook and try to use pandas_ta library. However, I can't import it. the error show that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'"

Please help me fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that *pandas_ta* is installed. If not, run:

```
! pip install pandas-ta
```

Then, import *pandas_ta*.

It worked for me with Jupyter Notebook 6.4.5 and Python 3.8.8.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice. I try as your suggestion but the error still occur. I already install pandas-ta in my jupyter via pip install. The pandas-ta is also show when I check with 'pip list' in my jupyter.

Comment: I found someone [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/867) with the same issue. It is possible that "dataclasses" is not fully installed. Try: `! pip install dataclasses`

Answer (score 0):

In case this is a current issue for anyone else, "import pandas_ta" didn't work for me. Instead I tried "import ta" and it worked.